# Como puedo buscar por la ultima palabra de la ruta en c#

Tags: c#

Hola me gustaria buscar por la ultima palabra de la ruta

Este es mi codigo: El problema en poner contains es que si un archivo contiene DI i CO busca por el primero, yo quiero que busque por la primera letra de la ruta completa es decir, en: "C:\test\csv\PRUEBA\Correcta diputacion" que entre en CO.

```
        string root = "C:\\test\\csv\\PRUEBA";
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(root);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(root);
        string valor = "";

        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries){
            
            if (fileName.Contains("DI")){
                valor = "di";
            }
            else if (fileName.Contains("CO")) {
                valor = "co";
            } 
            else if (fileName.Contains("AS")) {
                valor = "as";
            }
            else if (fileName.Contains("PA"))
            {
                valor = "pa";
            }
            else if (fileName.Contains("re"))
            {
                valor = "re";
            }
```

Comment: Con "_...la última palabra de la ruta_" te refieres al nombre del archivo?

Comment: Si pero si el archivo contiene Correcta diputacion pero quiero que solo coja Correcta

Comment: observa esto:  C:\test\csv\PRUEBA\Correcta **di**putacion ¿ tu string contiene *di*? si, asi que si es tu primera opción va a entrar siempre por ahi

Comment: Claro, lo que quiero es solucionar eso, intentar que en vez de contains si existe algo que solo coja la primera palabra en este caso seria Correcta y busque por CO

Comment: Creo que deberías replantearte esa parte, porque si, si se puede, puedes usar `var dividido = fileName.Split('\\');` y despues `dividido[dividido.Count-1]` pero conservarias el problema

Answer (score 1):

La clase [Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-5.0) contiene métodos que facilitan el trabajo con las rutas.

Con base en tu confirmación de que te refieres al nombre del archivo, propongo extraerlo y luego validar si "comenza por" de la siguiente manera:
*(omitiré parte de tu código para mantener el foco en el área de interés)*

```
//....
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
{
    //  |  Obtienes el nombre del archivo
    //  V
    string nombre = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
 
    //  |   Ahora haces las comparaciones con el nombre  
    //  V   
    if (nombre.StartsWith("DI"))
    {
            valor = "di";
    }
    else if //... continúa con el resto de las condiciones
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la forma mas adecuada y fácil es separar los componentes del path, toma el ultimo y luego utilizar Contains.

Te dejo una pequeña función que hace eso:

```
   private bool Contains(string fileName, string containsText)
   {
       string lastPath = fileName.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
       return lastPath.Contains(containsText);
   }
```

En el Split, utilizo Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, para que funcione tanto en linux como windows, pero se podría utilizar directamente ''.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
        string root = "C:\\test\\csv\\PRUEBA";
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(root);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(root);
        string valor = "";

        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {

            if (Contains(fileName, "DI"))
            {
                valor = "di";
            }
            else if (Contains(fileName, "CO"))
            {
                valor = "co";
            }
            else if (Contains(fileName, "AS"))
            {
                valor = "as";
            }
            else if (Contains(fileName, "PA"))
            {
                valor = "pa";
            }
            else if (Contains(fileName, "re"))
            {
                valor = "re";
            }

        }
```

Para que quede mas elegante y reutilizable te dejo esta clase de extensión:

```
public static class extensiones
{
    public static bool ContainsLast(this string fileName, string containsText)
    {
        string lastPath = fileName.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
        return lastPath.Contains(containsText);
    }

}
```

Y la utilizas de esta forma:

```
fileName.ContainsLast("DI")
```